# C++ RdKafka::Producer looses queued messages when broker restarts

Tags: c++, data-transfer

Testing my Kafka producer I found out that it cannot survive a short lasting Kafka outage.

I stop the server, make some minutes pause and start it again while my client produces messages.
After server start there comes Event Callback "partition count changed from 1 to 0" and "desired partition is no longer available (Local: Unknown partition)" and "topic does not exist (Broker: Unknown topic or partition)".
Then follow many Delivery Report Callback errors - MSG_STATUS_NOT_PERSISTED "Broker: Unknown topic or partition" on all the offline buffered messages.
Some seconds later comes the positive Delivery Report Callbacks - MSG_STATUS_PERSISTED and the following messages are produced as expected.

I tried to change auto.create.topics.enable server property to "true" and it helps - no messages now are lost on broker restarts.

Can I do something to use auto.create.topics.enable=false and not to loose messages?

Running kafka_2.13-3.4.0 on WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04.1 and using C++ library librdkafka v2.1.1.
Settings are: delivery.timeout.ms=86400000, retries=2147483647, acks=all,
and the topic is created with replication-factor 1, partitions 1.

Comment: It is possible people at https://serverfault.com/ know more

Comment: Thank you Gantendo, i've sent it there.